# Event Logger Pattern in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-cats

All of our backend services is written in Scala. We mostly write pure functional Scala using Cats.

I am trying to figure out if there is a design pattern in Cats or Scala in general that I can use to design a EventLogger.

This eventLogger should collects "events" (simple key values) as the request flows through the logic. At the end of the request, I want to write the collected events to data store. We already have a "context" implicit parameter that gets passed to all the methods. I could add this EventLogger to my Context class and it would have access to the event logger from most parts of my code. Now I am trying to figure out how to design the eventLogger itself, without using a mutable collection.

I have used to akka actors to collect states in the past to manage mutating states. I would prefer not to introduce Akka into our classpath just for this.

Comment: Why not use a `WriterT`?

Answer (score 2):

As @AndreyTyukin suggests, `Writer` would work well here.

You could do something like:

```
object EventLogger {
  type Event = (String, String)
  def log(event: Event): Writer[Vector[Event], Unit] =
    Writer.tell(Vector(event))
}
```

And then you could use it like this:

```
// Example usage
for {
  something <- Writer.value(myFunc(arg))
  _ <- EventLogger.log("function_finished" -> "myFunc")
  somethingElse <- Writer.value(myFunc2(arg2))
  _ <- EventLogger.log("function_finished" -> "myFunc2")
} yield combine(something, somethingElse)
```

At the end of this, you'll have some kind of `Writer[Vector[Event], ?]` value where the `?` might be a value you're interested in and the `Vector[Event]` is all of your `Event log` data ready for you to do something with.

Also usually `Writer` won't be the only container you want to use. You probably want to investigate [Monad Transformers](https://typelevel.org/cats/faq.html#a-idlistt-hreflisttawhere-is-listt) to stack up containers or something like [Eff](https://github.com/atnos-org/eff).